# Remove class and change aria-hidden value when clicking on body

Tags: javascript, dom

There is a project in the code pen called "Flex Priority Menu # 1.2" is a magnificent menu that when it has many links or the "resized" window, it is hiding and putting in a dropdown [More ...]. pure, the dropdown opens and closes with a click on itself. But I'd also like this dropdown menu to close when clicked anywhere else in the body.

Could someone give me a hand?

Thank you.

```js
// Variables for the priority nav
const priorityContainer = document.querySelector('.js-priority-menu');
const priorityMenu = priorityContainer.querySelector('.priority');
const overflowMenu = priorityContainer.querySelector('.overflow');
const overflowTrigger = priorityContainer.querySelector('.js-overflow-trigger');
const menuItems = priorityMenu.children;
const delay = 100;
let throttled = false;
let breakout = [];
let timeout = 0;

// Variables for the trigger svg 
const mySvg = document.querySelector('.js-svg-gradient');
const myGradient = mySvg.querySelector('.linearGradient');
const colours = [];

// Helpers could be shipped as part of an Object Literal/Module
const throttle = (callback, delay, scope) => {
  if (!throttled) {
    callback.call(scope);
    throttled = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      throttled = false;
    }, delay);
  }
};

// Initialise
const initialise = () => {
  checkNav();
  addListeners();
  makeStepGradient(colours);
}

/* return the current width of the Navigation */
const getPriorityWidth = () => {
  return priorityMenu.offsetWidth + 1;
}

/* return the break point of a menu item */
const getItemBreakPoint = item => {
  return item.offsetLeft + item.offsetWidth;
}

/* test breakpoint against menu width */
const itemBreaks = (breakPoint, menuWidth) => {
  return breakPoint > menuWidth;
}

/* test menuWidth against breakOut */
const itemBreaksOut = (index, priorityWidth) => {
  if (breakout[index] < priorityWidth) {
    return true;
  }
}

/* move item to overflow menu */
const addToOverflow = (item, itemBreakPoint) => {
  overflowMenu.insertBefore(item, overflowMenu.firstChild);
  breakout.unshift(itemBreakPoint);
}

/* remove from the overflwo menu */
const removeFromOverflow = (breaksOut) => {
  for (let item of breaksOut) {
    breakout.shift();
    priorityMenu.appendChild(item);
  }
}

/* Set button visibility */
const checkTriggerHidden = (value) => {
  if (value.toString() != overflowTrigger.getAttribute('aria-hidden')) {
    overflowTrigger.setAttribute('aria-hidden', value);
    checkNav();
  }
}

/* Check priority and overflow */
const checkNav = () => {
  /* check priorityMenu */
  let priorityWidth = getPriorityWidth();

  /* Iterate over the priority menu */
  let priorityIndex = menuItems.length;

  while (priorityIndex--) {
    let item = menuItems[priorityIndex];
    let itemBreakPoint = getItemBreakPoint(item);

    if (itemBreaks(itemBreakPoint, priorityWidth)) {
      addToOverflow(item, itemBreakPoint);
      //add colour to svg
      console.log(item);
      console.log(window.getComputedStyle(item).backgroundColor);
      let bgColour = window.getComputedStyle(item).backgroundColor;
      addToSVG(bgColour);
    };
  };

  /* iterate the overflow */
  let overflowIndex = overflowMenu.children.length;
  let breaksOut = [];

  while (overflowIndex--) {
    if (itemBreaksOut(overflowIndex, priorityWidth)) {
      breaksOut.unshift(overflowMenu.children[overflowIndex]);
      // remove colour from svg
      removeFromSVG();
    }
  }

  removeFromOverflow(breaksOut);

  /* check the trigger visibility */
  checkTriggerHidden(breakout.length == 0);
  
  makeStepGradient(colours);
}

/* Add Event listeners */
const addListeners = () => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    //throttle
    throttle(checkNav, delay);
    //debounce
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      checkNav();
    }, delay);
  })

  overflowTrigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    overflowMenu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', overflowMenu.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');
    overflowTrigger.classList.toggle('active');
  })
}

/* SVG indicator on the trigger */
/* Add to colour array */
const addToSVG = bgColour => {
  colours.unshift(bgColour);
}

const removeFromSVG = bgColor => {
  colours.shift();
}

const createStop = (offset, index, colour) => {
  let offsetValue = offset * index;
  let stop = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'stop');
  stop.setAttribute('offset', offsetValue + '%');
  stop.setAttribute('stop-color', colour);
  return stop;
}

const makeStepGradient = colourArray => {
  // Calculate offset values (%)
  const colourCount = colourArray.length;
  const offset = 100/colourCount;
  
  myGradient.innerHTML = "";
  // Loop the colours
  colourArray.forEach((colour, index) => {
    let stop1 = createStop(offset, index, colour);
    let stop2 = createStop(offset, index + 1, colour);
    myGradient.appendChild(stop1);
    myGradient.appendChild(stop2);
  });
}

/* Initilaise the menu */
initialise();
```

```css
      /* Structural */
.priority-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.priority-menu nav {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}
.priority-menu nav a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.priority-menu .priority {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.priority-menu .priority a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.priority-menu .overflow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
}
.priority-menu .overflow a {
  display: block;
}
.priority-menu [aria-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
.priority-menu [aria-hiiden="false"] {
  display: true;
}

/* Decorative */
body {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #2B3440;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #cbe4ed;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.priority-menu nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  color: #2B3440;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu10 {
  background-color: #A8E6CE;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu09 {
  background-color: #FFD3B5;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu08 {
  background-color: #f7e651;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu07 {
  background-color: #DCEDC2;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu06 {
  background-color: #A8E6CE;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu05 {
  background-color: #FF8C94;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu04 {
  background-color: #FFAAA6;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu03 {
  background-color: #FFD3B5;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu02 {
  background-color: #DCEDC2;
}
.priority-menu nav a.menu01 {
  background-color: #A8E6CE;
}
.priority-menu .overflow {
  border-top: 2px solid #2B3440;
}
.priority-menu .overflow-trigger {
  position: relative;
  background: #2B3440;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-left: 2px solid #2B3440;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.priority-menu .overflow-trigger .svg-gradient {
  width: 73px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  fill: url(#linearGradient);
}
.priority-menu .overflow-trigger span {
  position: relative;
}
.priority-menu .overflow-trigger.active {
  color: #cbe4ed;
}
.priority-menu .overflow-trigger.active .svg-gradient {
  fill: #2B3440;
  height: 46px;
  border: 1px solid #cbe4ed;
}

.blurb {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-priority-menu priority-menu">
  <nav class="priority">
    <a href="#" class="menu01">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu02">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu03">Menu Item 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu04">Item Item 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu05">Menu Item 5</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu06">Item Item 6</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu07">Menu Item 7</a>
  </nav>
  <button class="js-overflow-trigger overflow-trigger" aria-hidden="true">
    <svg class="js-svg-gradient svg-gradient" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linearGradient" class="linearGradient"
        x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0" spreadMethod="pad">
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
     </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="0" ry="0"/>
    </svg>
    <span>More...</span>
  </button>
  <nav class="overflow" id="overflow" aria-hidden="true" data-behaviour="menu"></nav>
</div>

<div class="blurb">
  <h1>Flex Priority Menu #1.2</h1>
  <p> Resize window to trigger the overflow nav drop down</p>
  <p>Pretty much the same as <a href='https://codepen.io/kungfuyou/pen/RaJaNZ'>Flex Priority Nav #1.1</a> but with a dynamic svg on as a menu indicator.</p>
  <p>To do: open / close state for the Menu trigger.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a listener to whole document body and hide the overflow menu when user clicks anywhere but on the `More...` button (which is handled by another function).

```
const addListeners = () => {
  //Other Listeners ...  
  document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.target != overflowTrigger && e.target.parentNode != overflowMenu) {
       overflowMenu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
       overflowTrigger.classList.remove('active');
     }
   })
}
```

---

In case you want it to work with right clicks too:

```
const addListeners = () => {
 //Other Listeners ...
 (['click','contextmenu']).forEach(event => {
  document.body.addEventListener(event, (e) => {
    if(e.target != overflowTrigger && e.target.parentNode != overflowMenu) {
      overflowMenu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
      overflowTrigger.classList.remove('active');
    }
  })
 })
}
```

---

[Edited Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaPZpe)

Comment: perfect, Just one more question. I wish that when I clicked the right mouse button, the "More" menu would close, except when the right click is inside it.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: This solution is great, but would like it not to be applied within the sub-menu "More"

Comment: That's how it works with the second listener. Note that the example on codepen implements the first listener.

Comment: I tested on Crhome and Firefox Quantum 57. But maybe I'm expressing myself wrong, I'm using google translator. I just wanted the right click effect not to just propagate within the "More" submenu. In the rest of the document it could also work to close the "More" menu but not inside it. You see?